# Numbers in three different formats

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a dataset; below you can see a small example.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
         'id':['9.','09', 9],
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = [
                                      'id',])

df['id'] = df['id'].replace(".","")


df
```

In this data set, one number is written in three ways e.g `'9.','09', 9`
Now I want to have all of these numbers written in the same way e.g 9, without . or 0

I tried with this line of code but it is not working

```
df['id'] = df['id'].replace(".","")
```

So can anybody help me how to solve this problem?

Comment: do you want the result be as `str` or `int`?

Comment: I expect result in int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```py
pd.to_numeric(df['id'])
```

```py
0    9.0
1    9.0
2    9.0
Name: id, dtype: float64
```

to int:

```py
pd.to_numeric(df['id']).astype(int)
```

```py
0    9
1    9
2    9
Name: id, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 3):

You could turn them all into doubles and then into integers

```
df['id'].astype('double').astype(int)
```

But this can be a problem for large numbers that exceed the 53 bit significand of the double. If the errant period is always at the end of the string, you could do

```
df['id'].astype(str).str.strip('.').astype(int)
```

or even a regex that strips the dot plus anything else to its right.